# Как узнать, какая кнопка в шаблоне листбокса была нажата?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Есть шаблон в листбоксе для отображения нескольких полей таблицы и есть кнопка удалить.
Я её могу связать с полем из таблицы и при этом узнавать, напротив какого значения была нажата кнопка.

```
<telerik:RadListBox >
    <telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Fio, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
               <Label Content="{Binding Path=value2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
               <Button Content="Х" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tag="{Binding Path=Fio}" Click="ButtonDelete_Click" Name="ButtonDelete"/>
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
  </telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

вот обработчик нажатия кнопки:

```
private void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string Fio = (string)btn.Tag;
    MessageBox.Show(Fio);
}
```

при этом я вижу, напротив какого фио была нажата кнопка.

А как узнать, какая по счёту была нажата кнопка, т.е. из какого `ListBoxItem` данного листбокса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

1.Назвать как-нибудь `ListBox`

2.Забиндить `Tag` кнопки на самого себя

3.Взять из `Tag` в обработчике элемент и найти его индекс из коллекции `Items`

4.(обращаю внимание, что общим классом, содержащим свойтсво `Tag`, является `FrameworkElement`)

5.(также для верного поиска индекса в этом случае требуется чтобы элементы не повторялись (если это не ссылочные типы). В противном случае нужно читать C# и включать "мозги";)

---

```
 <Button Tag="{Binding}" Click="ButtonDelete_Click" />
```

-

```
private void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object tag = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag;
    int index = TelerikListBox.Items.IndexOf(tag);
    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
}
```